# how to use getDerivedStatefromProps in my component

Tags: reactjs

The component receives a list of Objects as prop. I want to display it with infinite scroll.
It has the state "curNum", which is current number of items to be displayed. "curNum" changes when scroll down so the list of items is sliced based on the "curNum".

The list of object will be updated by the parent component, and "curNum" should be reset to initial value.

With componentWillReceiveProps I can do:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(newProps) {
  this.setState({
  curNum: initNum,
 });
}
```

but how can I rewrite it using  `getDerivedStateFromProps`? I read that the new method will be triggerged even if the state changes. So how can I know I am recieving new props?

Do I have to mirror a copy of the list to the sate and then deep check if the list of objects are equal every time?

Comment: You could try to use [`componentDidUpdate`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate) instead.

Comment: @KenoClayton, componentDidUpdate is supposed to handle side-effects and not update state

Comment: You're right, my mistake 

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways that you can use to update the state when props change

1. Use getDerivedStateFromProps: Note that its suggested that you avoid using this method as much as possible since this is called on each update  and initial render and not just on Parent component re-render or props change. If however you want to use it, you need to store the prevState too

Code:

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {

  if (state.prevCurNum !== props.initNum) {
     return {
         currNum: props.initNum,
         prevCurNum: props.initNum
     }
  } else {
      return { prevCurNum: props.initNum }
  }
}
```

2. Assign the state from props in constructor and control the key props to component

code

```
<MyComponent key={this.state.initNum} initNum={this.state.initNum} />
```

and in MyComponent

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state= {
       currNum: props.initNum
    }
}
```

In the above example if the prop `initNum` changes, the key to the component will change and it will result in the component to re-mount calling its constructor

3. The third way is to use memoization in render, but its mostly useful when the state is derived from a complex computation of props and isn't supposed to change locally.

Comment: initNum never changes. It is a constant. I want curNum to reset if props is changed

Comment: @assiegee, The above example is just to demonstrate. whatever props changes, you can make use of it

Comment: Thanks but your option2 will no longer be applied right? I am still wrapping my head on option1

Comment: @assiegee, Your parent must be passing some prop to the child which lets to its re-render right? or else because of some change in the parent it re-renders causing the child to re-render too, so you can constructor the key prop based on that change

Comment: As I said, I am passing an array of objects as a prop. I don't really think option 1 will work though... Since it will never falls in to the first condition if initNum never changes @shubham

Comment: I can't possibiliy pass a list of object as a key right?

Comment: You can't. but you can construct a key by stringifying it